# Transaction Management in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am doing a web application in asp.net.
I have a class **CommonDB** to save data.

```
public class CommonDB
{

    private static string GetConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db"].ToString();


    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString); 
        if (Con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Con.Close();
        }
        return Con;
    }

    public static int ExecuteNonquery(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        SqlConnection Con = GetConnection();

        Con.Open();

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = Con;               
            Con.Close();
            return ReturnVal;
        }


        catch
        {                
            Con.Close();
            return 0;

        }


    }
```

}
}

I am using the following function to save data

```
  public int AddGroupMaster() //Inserting
    {
        try
        {                
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "NV_Group_Master_Add";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group_ID", iGroupId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group_Code", strGroupName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group_Name", strGroupName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Created_On", strCreatedOn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modified_On", strModifiedOn);
            iReturn = CommonDB.ExecuteNonquery(cmd);
            return iReturn;
        }

        catch { return 0; }
    }
```

This function is called from code behind like :

```
   protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            objGroup.strGroupName = txtGroupName.Text.Trim();
            objGroup.strCreatedOn = DateTime.Today.ToString();
            objGroup.strModifiedOn = "";
            objGroup.AddGroupMaster();

        }

        catch
        {

        }

    }
```

I want to  use Commit and rollback. How it is possible in my coding??
Please suggest a solution

Comment: This is asp.net, not Classic asp

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, you will have to do that in your *CommonDB* library.

For example, your `ExecuteNonQuery` method would look like this:

```
public static int ExecuteNonquery(SqlCommand cmd) { 

    int retVal;
    SqlConnection Con = GetConnection();
    DbTransaction tran;

    try {
        cmd.Connection = Con; 
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        tran = cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction;
        cmd.Transaction = tran;
        retVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery;
        tran.Commit()
    } catch { 
        tran.Rollback();
        throw;
    } finally {
        cmd.Connection.Close()
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

And yes, do not forget to get a reference to `System.Data.Common`.